# Can I change the Anchor of a Path object in pathlib?

Tags: python, pathlib

I want to process files in a remote share and when I find a file I want, I want to copy it to my local machine.
Something like:

```
copy \\remote_server\share\path\to\file.txt d:\path\to\file.txt
```

I could do something like :

```
path_str = '\\remote_server\share\path\to\file.txt'
anchor_str = Path(path_str).anchor
new_path = Path(path_str.replace(anchor_str, 'd:'))
```

But is there a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't consider it more pythonic but instead [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) you could also make use of [`Path.relative_to`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to):

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r"\\remote_server\share\path\to\file.txt")

new_path = "d:\\" / path.relative_to(path.anchor)

print(new_path)  # d:\path\to\file.txt
```

---

**Side note** that may come handy for some readers: When I used [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) on my Linux machine, the [`anchor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.anchor) of an UNC path was not resolved correctly. However, it works when I use [`pathlib.PureWindowsPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PureWindowsPath).

[image]

```py
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath

# use PureWindowsPath instead of Path on Linux
path = PureWindowsPath(r"\\remote_server\share\path\to\file.txt")

new_path = "d:\\" / path.relative_to(path.anchor)

print(new_path)  # d:\path\to\file.txt
```